# Joint Account Signatories

Tags: joint-account, uae

If joint account have three signatories and instruction says account operates with joint signatures without any further specification of "any two", how many signatures are required to do financial transaction.

p.s. kindly refer if is there any reference.

This is for the UAE.

Comment: What country are you asking about?

Comment: You'll need to call the bank and ask.  It most likely depends on the rules of the bank and not laws.

Answer (score 2):

This is best answered by your Bank.

Generally if it is not specifically mentioned "any two"; all signatories need to sign. Some rules from [Arab Bank](http://www.arabbank.ae/en/accountopeningterms.aspx).